# How to associate .hl files to Clojure syntax highlighting in Light Table?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable, hoplon

I'd like to get Hoplon (http://hoplon.io/) code highlighted using Light Table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All you should need to do is this:

```
 :files [(:lt.objs.files/file-types [{:exts [:hl],
                                      :mime "text/x-clojure",
                                      :name "hl",
                                      :tags [:editor.clj :editor.clojure]}])]
```

in your `user.behavior` file.

Source:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/light-table-discussion/LjlYu6K1sWk

EDIT 5/1/15: The format of Light Table behavior files changed at some point. The following variation on the above worked for me:

```
 [:files :lt.objs.files/file-types [{:exts [:hl],
                                      :mime "text/x-clojure"
                                      :name "hl"
                                      :tags [:editor.clj :editor.clojure]}]]
```

Comment: On my system the file is called "user.behaviors" and doing the suggested above has no effect :(

Comment: try default.behaviours under settings

Comment: @boxed I had a similar issue when trying out the snippet. Did you copy and paste it in or type it in yourself? I ended up typing h1 "h-one" instead of hl "h-l" or "h-lima"

Comment: @jeemar well, I was trying to get another extension than .hl enabled so that won't apply to me :P

Comment: @boxed Ah, I see. Well, hope you solved your problem! :)

Comment: copy and pasted. worked for me. needed to reopen the hoplon file i was viewing.

Comment: this solution is for the old format of lighttable settings. it would be nice to have the solution in the new format.

Comment: @PPPaul: I made an edit just now showing a translation to the current format.